# Is there a way to disable check box in SWT TableColumn

Tags: swt

I have a SWT table with SWT.CHECK column. I want to populate another table based on the check box selection in the first table. I am achieving this using Table Selection. So, I want to disable the SWT.CHECK in the first table. Is there any way to disable to the check box?

Comment: Use Image instead of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Use `TableItem.setGrayed` (boolean grayed). Even though it is grayed out, still you can check/uncheck it. To disable check/uncheck, use `TableItem.setChecked(boolean checked)`

Comment: Sorry but I don't want the check box to be enabled.

Comment: Yes, that is why the last bit "To disable check/uncheck, use TableItem.setChecked(boolean checked)" is there. If a user cannot check or uncheck a box, and it's grayed out, it's disabled...... or did you try this before and it doesn't work? Let me know, and I'll help where I can.

Comment: setchecked is different from setenabled right ? And both are not available for tablecolumn

Comment: @Kutty TableColumn is the heading for a column, TableItem is the individual row. You can call setGrayed on the TableItem to gray the check box on a single row.